Could you compress chocolate such that it has the same density and shape as a real copper coin?
There are many cultures around the world that have traditions of chocolate coins around Christmas time, mine included. Recently I wondered if it was possible to compress chocolate to give it the same density as a real coin (which are mostly made of copper I believe, though the exact composition is not that important). There is no real purpose to this question, other than entertaining the idea that you could trick people into thinking these are actual currency instead of the chocolate kind.
Assuming a coin is made of 100% copper, it would have a density of about 8960 kg/m$^3$, whereas chocolate has a density of about 1300 kg/m$^3$. This means you would have to compress it to about 1/7th of its original volume. Since chocolate has a non-zero compressibility, I figure it is possible to get it to that density, but would the chocolate still retain similar physical characteristics during the process, or would the pressure needed cause other effects that make this impossible? I have little experience in the subject of material science, so I wasn't able to get to good information regarding chocolate under pressure, mostly about effects of chocolate on blood pressure.
Any chance someone has a hydraulic press to do a taste test afterwards?
Edit: Source for the density of chocolate
https://www.density.co.uk/documents/Density-of-Chocolate.pdf

You might ask this on [cooking.se].  Never heard of highly compressed chocolate before (and chocolate is a generic term covering a wide range of blends of ingredients).

Thanks @StephenG-HelpUkraine, I'll look into that, as I do realise this is a phyisics question a lot of physicists might not have the specific knowledge of.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine This is 100% physics question, not cooking question. It is useless to direct the author to the subsite about cooking because in the kitchen there is absolutely no equipment that could be used to compress chocolate to 1/7 of its original volume.

Interesting things happen at high pressure, even if done without heating the material. It would be very interesting what kind of crystalline structures it would produce.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/810536/how-much-pressure-would-it-take-to-compress-a-block-of-solid-steel-into-one-tent

"Any chance someone has a hydraulic press to do a taste test afterwards?" - Yes.

Something to keep in mind here--you very well might get some phase change issues with the sort of pressures involved.  Among other things the water will freeze, but into probably ice XI.  (Although I don't know the pressure so X and VII are also possibilities.)  I wouldn't be surprised if your chocolate gets changed.

Possibly an interesting alternative avenue to explore: your premise for the question is to fool people into thinking the coin is real by mimicking the weight of a real coin. Chocolate coins usually are not just chocolate: they are also usually wrapped in foil. I wonder if there is another material that could be used for the foil to make up for the weight lost to chocolate, while still being thin enough to not just be a real coin itself.

Reach out to YouTube's Hydraulic Press Channel to conduct the experiment (seriously).

NB there are aluminium coins in some countries.  Al is only about twice the density you give for chocolate.

@Duke You'd need a pretty high density to have much room for chocolate in the middle. Gold looks right, is edible, but is rather expensive; I'd rather keep lead, uranium,  and osmium out of my food, if you don't mind.

@JohnMcSwag certainly kitchen experience suggests it's denser that water (milk) but not massively so

@MichaelMcFarlane they're great, and they'd probably be up for it, but realistically it would squeeze out the sides without containment.

@MichaelMcFarlane someone already linked to a video of them (though the link is simply called yes, so it may be easy to miss, it was this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qipt0yUKt8). As Chris H mentioned, it simply squeezes out the side without containment.

The heroes we deserve are Bikos, D. et al., "Destructive and non-destructive mechanical characterisation of chocolate with different levels of porosity under various modes of deformation," 2023. They managed to achieve a permanent (inelastic) compression of about 3%. No word on how that affected the taste or mouthfeel.
For the behavior of chocolate under more extreme compression, further research is clearly needed. However, it might be interesting to look at the interior of the sun as a comparison. The sun is made of hydrogen. Liquid hydrogen reaches a density of about 70 kg/m$^3$ at 1 atmosphere, but obviously becomes denser under high pressures. To get the density 7 times higher, you have to go (very roughly) 40% of the way towards the center of the sun, at which point the pressure is about 20 TPa. [1] (For comparison, the pressure at the center of the earth is only 360 GPa.) Unfortunately, the high temperatures inside the sun are a confounding factor, and  chocolate is not the same as hydrogen [citation needed], but this should give you an idea of the extreme conditions required to achieve that kind of compression.
The bottom line is that a hydraulic press is not going to do the trick. If you want to compress chocolate to a density of 9, you are going to need to hire the engineers who design the explosive lenses used in nuclear weapons, and even that might not be enough.
[1] data from https://www.sns.ias.edu/~jnb/SNdata/Export/BP2004/bp2004stdmodel.dat

That's an interesting paper, thanks for the help. I did try to find the 3% in the paper, but I didn't see it directly. Did you take that from Fig 6c)? I'm not very familiar with this field so I might've missed it behind the jargon. Or just by missing in general

For the record: this means that chocolate cannot be easily compressed into the density of copper, it seems.

@JohnMcSwag I eyeballed it from figure 8. But I'm now noticing that their experimental design did not constrain the chocolate horizontally, so while the height permanently decreased by 3%, this might have been produced by an increase in the diameter of the column rather than a density increase. At  any rate, 3% is the upper bound for the density increase achieved in their loading-unloading experiment.

I have learned recently that the pressure at Earth's core-mantle boundary is enough to reduce the volume of granite by a factor of two.  However, putting chocolate in this environment would transform it into some sort of metamorphic rock, just like it does to the granite.  I don't know what chemical changes this pressure would cause without the amplifying effect of high temperature, but I would be shocked if the answer were "no chemical changes at all."

Fatman compressed the Pu core by roughly a factor of 2.5 (see, for example, American Journal of Physics 86, 105 (2018); doi: 10.1119/1.5009102).

Fats are slightly compressible. I highly doubt you'd get the desired density with any available compression technology, but I had no luck finding useful numbers. OTOH, high compression probably polymerises the cocoa butter into a form of wax, which would surely affect its taste.

Somebody needs to nominate Bikos et al. for an Ig Nobel prize.

As you say, heat is a confounding factor.  A major confounding factor in this case.  A diamond anvil cell can go to 100Gpa, what's the temperature at that 40% of the way location?

The main problem with eating chocolate under such high pressure is the needed decompression time after the event! ;-)

This answer is worthy of Randall Monroe's What If... series.

It is definitely theoretically possible -- given high enough pressures anything can be compressed to that density. However, there are multiple problems which would prevent you from tasting the product:

Bulk modulus of chocolate will be in gigapascals, and compressing it by a factor of seven would thus require pressures on the order of $10^{12}\ \mathrm{Pa}$. Such pressures are way too high to be achieved with non-destructive methods. It would require high (or maybe even nuclear) explosives.
Even if it were possible to design a sufficiently powerful press, you would not be able to taste it in the compressed state. When the pressure is removed, chocolate would expand back (nearly) to its original volume.
It is quite likely that irreversible chemical changes would happen, since the compression with explosives is necessarily very fast. I suppose that the final state of the matter would be a mix of carbohydrates that would resemble crude oil rather than chocolate.


Chocolate has traces of naturally occurring heavy metals such as cadmium. But Cadmium has a lower density than copper, unfortunately (or fortunately for the eater since cadmium is toxic). Otherwise, you could accomplish your objective by sufficiently increasing the proportion of denser components of chocolate.
However, if you added denser elements such as silver or gold, you could make an edible chocolate mixture as dense as copper. It would probably be expensive and not so tasty, but silver and gold are not toxic and should not harm anyone who eats them.
Zchocolat actually makes edible chocolate encrusted in gold. It's pricey.

How does this answer the question? The question is asking about compression and not replacing with metals.

How is cadmium having a lower density than copper fortunate with regard to toxicity?

@VincentThacker, you will find that 'chocolate' does not have a specific scientific chemical definition, and therefore, this answer is 100% applicable, since he is proposing a perfectly valid chocolate recipe that will achieve the desired density and shape as requested under 1 atmospheric pressure.

@crobar That has nothing to do with the question. The question is asking about compressing chocolate.

As others have remarked, the question asks about increasing the density of chocolate through compression, not by changing its ingredients. FWIW, I have eaten various Indian milk sweets decorated with silver and gold leaf, but the actual metal content is very small.

@PM2Ring, what are the ingredients of "chocolate" exactly.

@crobar That's irrelevant. The question clearly specifies that John wants to increase the density by compression, not by meddling with the ingredients.

"Chocolate has traces of naturally occurring heavy metals such as cadmium." -- [Citation needed]
